# Mathematicians working on social choice theory

Tags: soft-question, social-choice

Can someone tell me which mathematicians are actively working on social choice theory, or point to a place where they may be listed?

Comment: Wouldn't a more neutral way to phrase this question be "Can someone tell me which mathematicians are actively working on social choice theory?"

Comment: I imagine so... there's http://home.uchicago.edu/rmyerson/research/schch1.pdf for example. (And I got a book for Christmas written by the mathematician Donald Saari, *Chaotic Elections! A Mathematician Looks at Voting*, which is about the mathematics of voting patterns.) And I guess that Timothy Gowers is interested too, based on a series of recent blog posts which ends with this: http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/some-post-referendum-consolations/  Have you tried any of these? 

Comment: Noga Alon is interested (gave a talk at this at IAS this last fall).



Comment: That heavily depends on whom exactly you count as "mathematicians". IMHO, Herve Moulin (Rice University, Economics department) is certainly not a guy to miss. I consider him to be almost a pure mathematician (PhD in math., anyway) but you may disagree.

Comment: "Actively" I dunno, but Yuliy Baryshnikov (now at UIUC) did very nice work in the 1990s explaining that Arrow's theorem is a consequence of the non-contractibility of a certain simplicial complex parametrizing social preferences!  (In spirit this carries on work of Chichilnisky who I think was the first person to recognize the homotopic aspect of Arrow's work, and who proved similar theorems in other contexts.)

Comment: I think there is enough activity in the area to warrant some type of related tag on MO.

Comment: I did find a few related tags, fair division, game theory, mathematical economics.

Comment: I created a social-choice tag. I couldn't find the subject area on the arXiv. The closest two were *Social and Information Networks* (cs.SI) and *Physics and Society* (physics.soc-ph). Feel free to rename accordingly.

Comment: The nearest MSC 2010 subject code seems to be *91Cxx Social and behavioral sciences: general topics*.

Answer (score 6):

[A. Slinko](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~slinko/) publishes in social choice theory. (I am presently unable to post this answer as a comment to the OP's question.)

Comment: It's fine to post an answer; I didn't because it's far from an area of expertise for me. 

Comment: This is a good answer, worthy of being more than a comment.

Comment: I agree this was a great answer, by looking at his webpage, list of visitors and publications I found several others working in this field. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Graciela Chichilnisky](http://www.chichilnisky.com/showall_articles.php) is one of them (as well as her co-authors). Late Beno Eckmann has a nice chapter in one of his books on social choice theory as a direct application of an average rule in arbitrary spaces. Other people include Luc Lauwers or Shmuel Weinberger. These are examples of mainly algebraic topology at work.

On the other hand, social choice theory is a wide area. It ranges from aggregating preferences to voting and even mechanism design to some extent where tools applied are different.

Answer (score 1):

The [Center for the Study of Rationality](http://www.ratio.huji.ac.il/) at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem studies social choice theory among other things. See their [members list](http://www.ratio.huji.ac.il/members.php) for a list of quite a few mathematicians who have worked on social choice theory.